# How to pivot based on two column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

i have a table as follows

[image]

and my expected output is as follows.

[image]

[SQL Fiddle for this problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/201c6b/13)

In expected output ,it need to be pivoted by combination of id & date .

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any `PIVOT` function in sql lite. Which the link that you have supplied leads to. But you could do this:

```
SELECT
    yourtable.Id,
    yourtable.Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Type]=1 THEN [Value] ELSE NULL END) AS [1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Type]=2 THEN [Value] ELSE NULL END) AS [2],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Type]=3 THEN [Value] ELSE NULL END) AS [3]
FROM
    yourtable
GROUP BY
    yourtable.Id,
    yourtable.Date
```

If you want to do it with an pivot and are using MSSQL 2012. Then you can do this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
    yourtable.Id,
    yourtable.Date,
    yourtable.Type,
    yourtable.Value
FROM
    yourtable
) AS sourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value)
    FOR Type IN([1],[2],[3],[4])
) AS pvt
```

This will result in this:

```
1   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000 23  NULL    NULL    NULL
2   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000 56  NULL    NULL    NULL
3   2014-04-01 00:00:00.000 12  78      NULL    NULL
2   2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 56  NULL    NULL    NULL
3   2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 12  78      33      NULL
```